# how do you use the objects from a class if you change it to an abstract class and extend it in another class?

Tags: java

I want to turn a class I made into an abstract class and get another class to extend it. This is because the class (particle) is leaning heavily on the class I want to make abstract (vector).

I am not sure how I will use all those objects I instantiated with the new keyword or if it will totally mess things up. I am willing to try it to learn something about using the abstract classes in my own example but if anyone can help me understand what I am doing that would be great!

Comment: Please post some related code on how would you like to do. That helps in providing valid answer. Right now question is very vague.

Answer (score 1):

if your new class depends on vector then rather than inheriting it try composition ...
so lets say u want to make ur own Queue then its not good idea to inherit from vector rather have a data member of type vector .
this has many advantage over inheritance . If u need to change the container to some other say set u do not have to worry about changing interface. You still will have some add and remove interface to your class. So client code will be independent of the container you are using to generate Queue. 
Just on side notes : Consider using composition over inheritance. And look at some design patterns and try understanding when you need composition and when u can not avoid inheritance.

Comment: I think I might be using composition already. What is it that makes it better for this type of thing?

Answer (score 1):

from wht I understand you are trying to convert `class MyClass` to `abstract class AbstractMyClass`

So, If you convert MyClass to an abstract class all the statements like

```
AbstractMyClass myClass=new AbstractMyClass();
```

will give you an error as you cannot make an instance of an AbstractMyClass.
Also, if the situation is

```
abstract class AbstractMyClass
{
}
class ConcreteMyClass extends AbstractMyClass
{
}
```

then do can do something like

```
AbstractMyClass abstractMyClass=new ConcreteMyClass();
```

or the usual

```
ConcreteMyClass concreteMyClass=new ConcreteMyCLass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance : is a relation. More importantly the interface of base class and sub class should be same. Here u do not want client code to add new element using push_back()(for C++) but a mothod like add().So interface is different, a clear indication of wrong use of inheritance.Composition : has a and also "implemented in terms of". This is from Scott Mayer in effective C++. As with your case, u want implement a new DataStrucutre in terms of some thing. So composition is what you need. Now derived class does not need to have same interface. In general if you find interface to be same its more like inheritance and if not composition. There are tons of other advantage of compositon on inheritance. Just google or pick any good design book.